# .htaccess not working as expected for /public/ redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

So, I am working on this php framework of my own called [PHP Launcher](https://github.com/hind-sagar-biswas/php_launcher). There I have `.htaccess` to acheive the following:

1. if project is  in a sub dir of server's root dir, then `RewriteBase /sub_dir/`
2. if it tries to access `assets/` or `node_modules/` folder then access those
3. else, redirect everything to `core/index.php` which'll handle internal routing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/node_modules/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ core/index.php [L,QSA]
```

But with this I faced a problem that if I wanted to index my site to google or any other search engine, they'd need to access a `.xml` file in the url or `robots.txt` etc. So, I decided to make a `public/` folder that'll contain static files that can be access directly.

So, what I want is **If not `/assets/` or `/node_modules/` but files (`.html`, `.php`, `.xml`) the redirect it to retrieve from `/public/` directory else redirect to `core/index.php`**:

| Request Url | Expected Rediect |
| --- | --- |
| url/sub_dir/assets/whatever.css | url/sub_dir/assets/whatever.css |
| url/sub_dir/node_modules/whatever.css | url/sub_dir/node_modules/whatever.css |
| url/sub_dir/whatever.xml | url/sub_dir/public/whatever.xml |
| url/sub_dir/whatever/route/ | url/sub_dir/core/index.php |

So, *(as I am noob to `.htaccess` I tried GPT and Bard)*  the new htaccess code I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/node_modules/

# Exclude existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Exclude files with extensions .html, .php, .xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html|php|xml)$ [NC]

# Rewrite to /public/ directory
RewriteRule ^ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# If not matching the above conditions, rewrite to core/index.php
RewriteRule ^ core/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Now when I try: `url/sub_dir/whatever.xml` I got: `url/sub_dir/public/sub_dir/whatever.xml`

Demo: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=56cf3e90-8106-4961-bb95-83877a834abc

So, What is causing this and what's the solution?

[**Note:** To those who are always excited to close other's question as duplicate without checking if it is even duplicate or not, Yeah I did try searching for this and even read other related qyestions on stackoverflow and those either did not work or not coincide with the above problem as you should know how tricky htaccess can get!]

Comment: A note to your note in the question: the spirit here is generally positive and constructive. If someone votes to close a question that is usually not out of bad temper or meant in an evil way, but to keep this site what it is: usable and valuable. To impute such is not really a nice thing to write. Instead, for your next questions, you could explain why _exactly_ the existing solutions you found did _not_ work for you (just stating "did not work" has never helped anyone anywhere at any time).

Comment: And a general hint for you to improve your rewriting skills: stop using toys like those AI-Bots. They usually create broken code, why ever. Which hardly really helps to learn, for sure they are questionable teachers. Instead I would like to suggest that you take a look into the official documentation of the apache modules. Those are of excellent quality and come with great examples. You will learn a lot. Here that would be the rewriting module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html